# Trigonometric Word Problem Law of Sine and Cosine

Tags: trigonometry

A bridge is built across the top of two buildings of the same height. The length of the bridge is 10 m. If from a point on the ground between the two buildings, the angles of elevation of the ends of the bridge are 68 degrees and 62 degrees, how high are the buildings?

Can i solve this using (law of Sine) and ( law of Cosine) ?

Comment: first, law of sine then Pythagorous theorem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following figure.

[image: building_height]

Points $B$ and $C$ are the endpoints of the bridge.  Point $A$ is the point on the ground from which the angles of elevation are measured.

Observe that

\begin{align*}
\tan(68^\circ) & = \frac{h}{x}\\
\tan(62^\circ) & = \frac{h}{10~\text{m} - x}
\end{align*}

Solving the equation

$$\tan(68^\circ) = \frac{h}{x}$$

for $h$ yields

$$h = x\tan(68^\circ)$$

Solving the equation

$$\tan(62^\circ) = \frac{h}{10~\text{m} - x}$$

for $h$ yields

$$h = (10~\text{m} - x)\tan(62^\circ)$$

We can solve for $x$ by equating the two expressions for $h$.

\begin{align*}
x\tan(68^\circ) & = (10~\text{m} - x)\tan(62^\circ)\\
x\tan(68^\circ) & = 10~\text{m}\tan(62^\circ) - x\tan(62^\circ)\\
x\tan(68^\circ) + x\tan(62^\circ) & = 10~\text{m}\tan(62^\circ)\\
x[\tan(68^\circ) + \tan(62^\circ)] & = 10~\text{m}\tan(62^\circ)\\
x & = \frac{10~\text{m}\tan(62^\circ)}{\tan(68^\circ) + \tan(62^\circ)}
\end{align*}

Substituting for $x$ in the equation

$$h = x\tan(68^\circ)$$

yields

$$h = \frac{10~\text{m}\tan(62^\circ)\tan(68^\circ)}{\tan(68^\circ) + \tan(62^\circ)} \approx 10.69~\text{m}$$

which is about the height of a three-story building.